# How to create a separate file per module in Angular2 + Webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack

I followed the steps in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html and was able to get it working.

But what I want is to have a separate file per module.

I tried adding a new entry point in `webpack.common.js` for each module but it returns an error when building the app.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts',
        'test': './src/app/test/test.module.ts'
    }
    .....
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use webpack's `code-splitting` with `angular2`'s `loadChildren` method available in the route config. something like,

```
{
    path: 'yourroute', loadChildren: () => require.ensure('./yourmodule', (comp: any) => {
      return comp.default;
    }),
    ....
    ...
}
```

Here, the `yourmodule` would be loaded `on-demand` when the `yourroute` route is requested.

Comment: I encountered an error when I tried this. `Property 'ensure' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'.
`. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: I guess it is problem with typings included.. you might have used both requirejs d.ts and node.d.ts. remove require d.ts use only node.d.ts

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I got this working by following the steps here -> [Angular 2 lazy loading with Webpack](https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-lazy-loading-with-webpack-d25fe71c29c1#.c1v0gzgbo)

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple entry points you can pass an object to the entry option. Each value is treated as an entry point and the key represents the name of the entry point.

When using multiple entry points you must override the default output.filename option. Otherwise each entry point would write to the same output file. Use [name] to get the name of the entry point.

eg

```
entry: {
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
    vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
    app: './src/main.ts',
    test: './src/app/test/test.module.ts'
}
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].entry.js"
}
```

Try that without the quotes on the Left hand side. Also take note of the output

For more information please refer to [Webpack multiple entry points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html)